# Deserializing multiple elements from XElement

Tags: c#, linq, xml

I'm serializing multiple elements using this code:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers(xmlString)
{
  var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
  var customers = xml.Elements("Customer");
  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer));
  return customers.Select(c =>
  {
    using (var reader = c.CreateReader())
      return (Customer)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
  });
}
```

I have this hunch that `CreateReader` is an expensive one, so:

- Is there a way to serialize multiple elements out a collection of elements (without creating a `Customers` class)?
- Do I need to dispose all those readers?
- Any other way to read directly from `XElement` (should I use `string`)?

**Update**
I've initially asked the question with this code:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers(xmlString)
{
  var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
  var customers = xml.Elements("Customers");
  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer));
  return customers.Select(c => (Customer)serializer.Deserialize(c.CreateReader()));
}
```

Comment: XmlReader implements IDisposable then you **must** dispose it. An XML reader will _move_ to next element then you can create it just once, after each deserialized element **it'll move to sibling element** (but you have to handle end of list). About **performance**: do you have any **measured issue** with CreateReader()? Overhead isn't small but it's not big and I'd keep it (more) readable unless you have a problem here, especially because its overhead compared to serialization itself is pretty small...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [initial revision](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/108009/1) is fine. If you take a look at the [implementation at Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs.html#37f42b13494c015a) you'll see that the `XmlReader` returned by `CreateReader` is lightweight and that calling `Dispose` on it is not necessary.

---

```
...
var customers = xml.Elements("Customers");
...
```

It seems a little strange that you pick elements of type `"Customers"` and deserialize them as `Customer`. They should be `"Customer"` in the XML if they represent a single customer each.

Comment: The API creator returns a list of multiple `SelectCustomers` elements... How poor a naming is that, but once I saw how returns `Guid`s, `decimal`s and other types as `string` nothing is consistent. Something I've never seen in my 10 years as a dev... Anyway I've fixed my question.

Comment: @Shimmy I've seen similar naming with auto generated XML from 3rd parties. It's sad when their less than optimal naming have to end up in your own code.

Comment: I'm talking to their programmer and she doesn't understand why returning/accepting `Guid` as `string` is not better than returning it as a `Guid`...